# changing the domain name for artifactory URL

Tags: jetty, artifactory

1- I installed Artifactory on my local centos host and could successfully bring it up as `http://my-vm:8081/artifactory.`
2- To bring it up as https, I created a keystore as given [here](http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/09/10/configure-ssl-on-jetty-server-to-run-it-with-https/#comment-12277) and I was successful in accessing it as `https://my-vm:8443/artifactory`
3- The problem is I need to use my company's wild card certificate as per my company policy. So I also imported my company's key which is in pcks format into the existing keystore created in step 2.
Now I am still able to access it as `https://my-vm:8443/artifactory`, but to be trusted by my company's other tools and products, it needs to be `https://my-vm.company.com:8443/artifactory`. How can change this my-vm to my-vm.company.com?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with this in Jetty specifically, but you'll need to create a [virtual host](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Virtual_Hosts) for vm.company.com.